# Does Wipeout HD Fury (disc) support 3D?

Tags: stereo-3d, wipeout-hd

I am one of those guys that prefer buying games on discs instead of getting them "virtually" from online stores.

Thus I wanted to buy *Wipeout HD Fury* (PS3) on disc, but found some forums that complained about the disc version not supporting 3D. Apparently 3D only would work with the downloaded version.

My TV and PS3 are 3D-capable, and the *Wipeout HD* Demo also works in 3D already. But what about the disc version? Has anyone tried this?

Comment: I have the same problem, I hope in one update for the disc version to enable 3D. It's very irritating.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm only finding the same information online that you're probably seeing - forums with complaints about the disc version not supporting 3D. But I'm finding it from enough different sources that it looks like you're correct - the disc-based version doesn't support 3D.

I've had the PSN version for quite a while and it's a fantastic game even without 3D support. (I don't have a 3D-capable TV anyway.) So either way you'll have fun with it.

You could buy the disc-based version and hope for a patch, but if you really have to have the 3D I'd recommend getting the PSN version. I understand your preference for a physical copy though - I'd have bought the disc version if it were available at the time.

Comment: Hm... I already thought about getting the disc from some game rental store to just try it out. But I figured a SE question might be quicker and for free :)