# How to enable 3D in WipEout HD Fury Blu-Ray disc version

Tags: ps3, stereo-3d, wipeout-hd, wipeout-hd-fury

I'm trying to run `WipEout HD Fury` in `3D`. I have the `Blu-Ray disc version`, a `Samsung UE46C7000` series which has the `3D` option - in facts I can easily play `Killzone 3` with that option automatically detected.

I've been unable to find any way to unlock 3D view in `WipEout HD Fury` game, and couldn't find anything in the game manual - but I've read on various sites that `WipEout HD` and `Fury` content does supports 3D.

Is there any way to enable it?

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the retail disc version, this is relevant: [Does Wipeout HD Fury (disc) support 3D?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14368/does-wipeout-hd-fury-disc-support-3d)

(Hint: It's not good news...)

Comment: It's nonsense the disc version doesn't support 3D. They must plan to make an update for this, because like me, thousands of people has brought wipeout partially because of 3D capability.

Comment: Have you tried following the steps on this page? http://www.flatpanelshd.com/news.php?subaction=showfull&id=1276274018

Comment: yes, i've wrote this question after tried the guide in the same link